# Execute a keybind on a different application from python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, key-bindings, hotkeys, pywinauto

It's kind of hard to explain. Maybe the result is out there but I couldn't find it.

Simply put; I would like to run hotkeys on a program running on my desktop (Windows) via Python.

I have a 3rd party program that I have assigned certain hotkeys/keybindings to. For example when ctrl+Fn5 keys are pressed a certain command executes on that program.

What I want to do via Python scripts is to execute the mentioned hotkey (like ctrl+Fn5) on that program. (as if that program had focus on it and those keys were pressed)

I have been trying to do it via win32com.client. But the program itself doesn't allow that feature directly via its libraries. I also tried pywinauto but again it doesn't provide the libraries needed (tried analyzing it with other tools like swapy).

I have used catching hotkeys on python before. But they were for the Python application itself.

for example:

```
def keyPressEvent(self, e):
    if e.modifiers() & Qt.ControlModifier and e.modifiers() & Qt.ShiftModifier and e.key() == Qt.Key_V:
    # do somthing
```

What I need is to execute the hotkeys with the focus on the other program.

I looked into the os module to see if there was anything there that could help me but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Using pywinauto modules i got it to work. The trick was getting the focus on the program itself.

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
from pywinauto.keyboard import SendKeys

app = Application().connect(path='path_to_programs_exe_file')
app_dialog = app.top_window()
app_dialog.maximize()
app_dialog.set_focus()

SendKeys('^{F5}')
```